# Implementing 'successful git branching model' step by step

Tags: git, git-flow

So I've started to implement [this model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

I'm completely newbie to Git and software implementation process so I've listed everything I've done so far below. I need your help with some question that I've got and maybe some recommendations if you see that I don't understand something or move in the wrong direction. I believe that this could be a great help to others embarking on this path. So here is what I've done so far. I have the following structure of my website

```
/var/www/mysite.com/
                kohana
                    kohana files
                www
                    index.php
                    other files
```

To implement the model I've done the following:

1. I initialized the repository to clone bare repository from and made initial commit:

   ```
   cd /var/www/mysite/
   git init
   git add .
   git commit - 'initial commit'
   ```
2. I added shared user to place 'central repo' (shared bare repository) inside:

   ```
   - adduser git
   - su git
   - cd
   ```
3. I cloned repository to this user's folder. This will be the 'origin' repository.

   ```
   git clone --bare /var/www/mysite.com mysite.git;
   cd mysite.git;
   ```
4. I added second main branch 'develop' and now there are two branches 'master':

   ```
   git branch develop;
   git branch -a
       *master
       develop
   ```
5. I added users that will be developing the product:

   ```
   adduser maximus
   adduser len4ik
   ```
6. I created ssh keys for them and put to .ssh directories:

   ```
   su maximus; 
   mkdir .ssh;
   cd ~/.ssh;
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "maximus@example.com";
   su len4ik; 
   mkdir .ssh;
   cd ~/.ssh;
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "len4ik@example.com";
   ```
7. I created public repositories for each of them

   ```
   su maximus; cd;
   git clone /home/git/mysite.git;
   su len4ik; cd;
   git clone /home/git/mysite.git;
   ```

Now my developers will install TortoiseGit on Windows, set up ssh keys and pull from their public repositories to repositories created locally with TortoiseGit on Windows.

I have a few questions:

1. At step 4 what branch should be selected? It's 'master' now, but do I need to switch it to 'develop' maybe?
2. I assume that users will be pushing to and pulling from their public repositories (`/home/user/mysite`). How their commits are going to end up in 'central repo' which is `/home/git/mysite.git` ?
3. How those users will be able to checkout branches and get updates from 'central repo'?
4. At what point do I need to create realease and feature branches? Do I need to create them on 'central repo' (`/home/git/mysite.git`)?

Comment: Why do you need per user "public repositories"?

Comment: That's what I assumed I need from the model's explanation and also from [this chapter of Git pro book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) where it's shown that each developer has its own public repository

Answer (score 1):

1) You can choose whichever branch you want to develop on - it can either be master or develop. I would recommend trunk/master -branch-based development (in which case, I would suggest to delete the develop branch itself).

2) Users will have to setup their version of master to track your repo (in this case, git can act just like any other non-dvcs SCMs - ie having a central repo where every committer pushes to/pulls from). By setting this following/tracking, then they can push to their "remote".

3) Same as above, they can pull/push from the remote/central repo.

4) If you are following a Continuous Delivery/Deployment model, you dont need feature/release branches. If not, then I would suggest a branch for each release. Feature-branches can be done, but preferrably should be short-lived. In this case, master [branch] is truly the master [copy of your codebase].

Comment: Thanks! I would like to implement the model with uses distributed workflow, while you suggest that I use central workflow.